# checkbox by passing different type of value

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, handlebars.js

I am using **handlebar** to display the value. When a checkbox is checked the hidden input can't define whether the checkbox is checked or not. My question is: how can i pass the **invoice NO** and **total amount** "ID" to another page at the same time, because i need to display the selected invoice on the payment page. So can you recommend a solution for this?

I have provided a screenshot and my code below.

[image: auto sum up the total amount when checked]

```
<table data-role="table" id="tblInvoice" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterTable-input" class="table-stroke table-stripe ui-responsive"><!--without cellpadding-->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="8" style="text-align:center;font-size:20pt;">Open Invoices</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="10%"><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"/></th>
            <th>Company_code</th>
            <th>Invoice No.</th>
            <th>Invoice Type</th>
            <th>Invoice Date</th>
            <th>Due Date</th>
            <th>Invoice Status</th>
            <th>Open Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
{{#if invoices}}
    {{#invoices}}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="selected_open[]"  id="checkInvoice" value="{{open_amount}}" style="display:{{display}};" type="checkbox" />
                <input name="selected_invoice_no[]"  id="checkamount" value="{{invoice_no}}" type="hidden"/>
            </td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;" name="company_code">{{company_code}}</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;" name="invoice_no">{{invoice_no}}</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;" name="invoice_type">{{invoice_type}}</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;" name="invoice_date">{{invoice_date}}</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;" name="due_date">{{due_date}}</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;" name="status"><font color="{{color}}">{{status}}</font></td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;" name="open_amount">{{open_amount}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/invoices}}
{{else}}
        <tr>
            <th colspan="7"><div style="font-style:italic; color:red; text-align:center;">No Open Invoice</div></th>
        </tr>
{{/if}}
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

jquery table (handlebar)

```
var $cbs = $('input[name="selected_open[]"]');
function calcUsage()
{
    var total = 0;

    $cbs.each(function() {
        if (this.checked)
        {
            total += parseInt(this.value);
        }

    });
    $("#select_total").text('MYR' + total);//select_total = total amount ID
}

//For  checkboxes
$cbs.click(calcUsage);
```

The function of calculate the sum

Comment: Screenshots are not very helpful. Please copy and paste the contents of your screenshots into the question instead. Both the code and the error messages.

Comment: I just edited my original post. Hope that u guys can understand that why i asking for

Comment: You did a great job! I've tightened up the wording a bit for you as well.